# C++ - strange time measurements with and without if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, increment, performance-testing

I stumbled upon a strange duration difference between two equivalent increment syntax.

```
if(seed != state) ++i;
```

this notation measures 2.25 ms per 1048576 iterations

```
i += (seed != state);
```

and this 2.80 ms per 1048576 iterations.

Shouldn't the second notation be a bit faster than the first?
It is to mention, that seed == state happens very rarely (in 1 of 2^32-1 times).

Thanks for your answers.

Edit:
I tested the same thing with the gcc C compiler and there the first was slightly faster than the second, but the second was the same speed as with  the C++ compiler.

Comment: did you measure with optimized build? that would be surprising.

Comment: That is not enough time for reliable measurements under an operating system. Run that several times, you will probably get varying results. Let it run with a billion iterations, and the difference will probably disappear. If not, how do you compile this? Specifically, with or without optimizations? I'd expect an optimizing compiler to generate the exact same code for this, but possibly not without optimizations.

Comment: it runs with 1 billion iterations, but the result is divided by 1000 to get the average of 1 million runs. Even with -O3 the first one is a bit slower.

Comment: I had to check the math to make sure that's viable, comes out to ~8 ticks per iteration at ~3.3Ghz, so that's a viable number.  Viable enough that it seems unlikely the compiler did any weird precompution optimizations.

Comment: wait, the first one is a bit slower?  I thought the first one is a bit faster.

Comment: @Mike Nakis sorry you are right I mixed sth up.

Comment: What CPU are you using?  Which compiler? Can you please show us the assembly emitted by the compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `if` statement, the compiler can translate the increment to a conditionally executed statement (at least with processors that support conditionally executed statements).

The second example will *always* perform an addition of 1 or zero.

This is micro-optimization and really depends on the processor and its support system (caches, branch prediction, etc.)  For example, the 2nd example may be faster because there is no decision jump.  The first example may be faster on processors that have branch prediction.  The difference between the two may be negligible on processors that can fit the code fragment into the instruction cache (and not need to fetch other instructions).

I'm surprised that the code execution is in milliseconds.  Most modern processors should be executing in nanoseconds for those examples.

Comment: I converted nano to milli just for fun.

Comment: @bakkaa: really, you should be downvoted for giving wrong facts "for fun". For example, I wondered what CPU architecture you might be using, and concluded that it must be some ancient microcontroller clocked at less than 1MHz , because it takes *milliseconds* to compute.

Comment: @Marcus Müller: I didn't give wrong facts. You should be downvoted for not listening. I said I converted it from nano to milli but the time is the same. 1 million nanoseconds are 1 millisecond. You should know this.

Comment: aaaaah ok, sorry then

Answer (score 3):

The `if` version incurs a conditional branch instruction. The other just promotes a bool to an int and adds it.

Edit:

I would lean toward using the first one, <del>since technically the conversion `(int)true` isn't required by the standard to result in `1`; it's only required to result in "not zero." Though in practice, I've never seen a `bool` to `int` conversion that didn't use `1` for `true`.</del>

Comment: "... and *unconditionally* adds it."

Comment: it doesn't add in only 1 of 2^32-1 cases.

Comment: The edit is wrong, "non zero" evaluates to `true`, but `true` _always_ evaluates to `1`.  C++11 §4.5/6 "A prvalue of type bool can be converted to a prvalue of type int, with false becoming zero and true becoming one."

Comment: @MooingDuck Not just prvalues. [conv.integral]/4 (4.7) about integral conversions: "If the source type is bool, the value `false` is converted to zero and the value `true` is converted to one." `==` has result type `bool` as per [expr.eq] and [expr.rel] ([expr.eq] refers to [expr.rel]). That should cover all bases.

Comment: I guess long ago I misinterpreted the `int` to `bool` conversion rules as applying to `bool` to `int` as well.

Comment: It is not entirely correct to say that it just promotes a bool to an int.  The bool must somehow be computed, and prior to the introduction of the conditional move instructions computing the bool on a x86 architecture required either a conditional jump or a few other non-jump instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You never know what your compiler does to optimize your code. Branch prediction would actually make the first one faster. The second one depends on the comparison actually being carried out, and the result being added to `i` as 1 if true (which, depending on your CPU, but likely) will introduce a "dummy" 1-loaded register.

Comment: Due to your comment under Thomas Matthews answer, it seems you misunderstood me Marcus Müller. Please consider to read it again.

Answer (score 0):

The first one could conditionally not perform the add as a result of branch prediction. The second one is going to add every cycle because no option to skip the add is available. The result of the comparison will always be added to i.

I would assume that you will find that the first one is not performing the add every loop, but only occasionally when branch prediction fails.

Comment: the add is not performed in only 1 of 2^32-1 cases